# Emacs markdown-mode error on preview: "bin / bash: markdown: command not found"

Tags: markdown, emacs24, installation

I am using emacs 24 on fedora 17. I installed `markdown-mode`, but whenever I try to export a file by typing `C-c C-c m` or `C-c C-c p` in emacs, I got this error:

> /bin/bash: markdown: command not found

[image: Screenshot of emacs' markdown error message]

I read that this is probably an issue with the path variable, so I compared the `env` variable by typing `$ env` at the command line and `Esc-! env RET` in emacs. I found the path variable description is the same in both cases.

What is this error? How can I fix it and execute markdown previews from within emacs?

Comment: What is your path for the markdown.pl script?  What happens when you call the markdown script from bash?

Comment: Thank you for your reply & excuse me, I'm still newbie rummaging in the guts of software. That script you ask about has .pl (Perl isn't) file extension. I just followed instructions included in the package itself and saw no other requirement than place the .el file in the emacs load-path and let my emacs init file know about autoloading. Then, I tried the automatic way by typing at emacs `M-x package-install markdown mode` just if it were a dependencies problem. How might I check for the markdown.pl script? Scripts installed by the latter way said don't include any .pl file.

Comment: OK, I think, I'm following you now. For further references I recommend this [reading](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-command-not-found-error-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it/). So, by typing at cli `$ which markdown` or `$ which markdown-mode` I got: `no markdown-mode in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/txe/.local/bin:/home/txe/bin)`. but, I'm still at the same point, so any clue is welcomed.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I think. As reference for others looking for this same. I should also install, in my case, the proper package `$ sudo yum install python-markdown2`or $ sudo yum install [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) which offers to be like a swiss army knife when is about converting files from a markup format  into another. Thanks anyway to everyone. This log post will be probably useful to anyone in the same point.

Comment: Ok after lot of testing, markdown is the best for me `$ yum install python-markdown2` then `$ ln -s /usr/bin/markdown2 /usr/local/bin/markdown` (thanks again, RupertPupkin ✪ fedora-forums)

Comment: For Ubuntu users, this would be `sudo apt-get install markdown`.

Answer (score 53):

Install any markdown generating tool as you like,
for example [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Then add the following line to your `.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(markdown-command "/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
```

Comment: Just a reminder: In my case, after installing the `pandoc` using `apt-get install` , command for markdown is just  ` " pandoc"`

Comment: This worked for me, after I installed markdown with "brew install markdown".  I think this can be marked as the answer.

Comment: `brew install pandoc` on OS X

Comment: Can confirm this works on Windows too. Got pandoc windows release from github, extracted it, and set the path in emacs. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

This error occurs when you do not have a [markdown parser](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) installed. Installing one is simple with [brew](http://brew.sh/). From the command line:

`brew install markdown`

This should result in something like:

```
==> Downloading http://daringfireball.net/projects/downloads/Markdown_1.0.1.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
  /usr/local/Cellar/markdown/1.0.1: 2 files, 40K, built in 2 seconds
```

Before running that command, I had the same error you did. After running that command, which installs a markdown parser on your system, the emacs commands `C-c C-c m` and `C-c C-c p` worked as expected by opening an HTML version of my markdown file in either another buffer or the browser, respectively.

Comment: This is a nice easy way to get a copy of `markdown`, but the commands you referenced didn't work for me until I mapped the `markdown` parser to the `markdown-command` in my `~/.emacs` like so: `(custom-set-variables '(markdown-command "/usr/local/bin/markdown"))`

Answer (score 8):

You just need to pick and install a markdown parser:

- [rdiscount](https://github.com/davidfstr/rdiscount) (`gem install rdiscount`).
- python2-markdown (`yum install python-markdown2`)
- or some other.

Then, in emacs:

```
M-x customize-mode RET markdown-mode
```

Set 'Markdown Command' to the name of the executable you installed -- for example, `rdiscount` or `/usr/bin/markdown2`.

Answer (score 3):

- Add emacs package repository to `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

- Refresh packages:

`M-x package-refresh-contents`

- Install emacs major mode markdown-mode by evaluating:

`M-x package-install RET markdown-mode RET`

- Install markdown processor for your operating system:

```
brew install pandoc
#OR
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

- Verify pandoc installation:

```
which pandoc
# returns /usr/local/bin/pandoc
```

- Map the markdown parser in `init.el`:

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(markdown-command "/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setting up the markdown-command, there is a [thread](https://gist.github.com/fredRos/0e3a845de95ec654538f) about displaying it in github way, through pandoc.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated to a new machine recently and it looks like in macOS Monterey (maybe before) it looks like brew changed where it is installed. I changed my markdown-command to `"/opt/homebrew/bin/pandoc"` based on Saurabh's answer