# How can I preview markdown in Emacs in real time?

Tags: emacs, markdown

I'm using spacemacs and I'm looking for a plugin to preview markdown in real time. I have found a plugin [markdown-preview-eww](https://github.com/niku/markdown-preview-eww), but it requires a gem and I prefer not to install ruby.

The [markdown-mode](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) just exports md to html, and it can't preview markdown in real time. Also, I don't like to generate any file without my agreement.

So, is there any plugin to preview markdown in emacs? Or does everyone use org-mode in emacs rather than markdown?

Comment: This isn't a programming question; it's more likely to be on-topic on the [emacs.se] site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general Emacs question, not about writing or compiling programs.

Comment: Scroll down a bit and check for the best answer in 2020. I have tested *livedown-mode*, *flymd* and *impatient mode*, and IMHO the one that works better is `grip-mode`. The only drawback is that it has python/pip dependency.

Comment: I came here led by search engine because I have the same problem. In Emacs, solutions involving addons for live-updating became rather cumbersome and sub-optimal. I ended up opening a `md` file directly in a browser with an addon s.a. `Markdown Viewer`. It works great. Every time I save changes, the content in a browser is updated, at least on linux systems. You can also select a proper theme, s.a. light or dark Github. It's much smoother solution for me.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There are a few solutions listed here: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Markdown#Live_preview_as_you_type.

The pure-Emacs (nearly) solution and easy one, requiring no extra library from Python or Nodejs, is **impatient-mode**.

#### Impatient-mode

It's designed to work with html but the doc gives a trick to make it work with markdown. It also works like a charm but requires one configuration step:

- Install impatient-mode with `M-x package-install RET impatient-mode RET`, given you have configured package.el to use the [melpa](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Melpa) repository.
- Start an emacs' web server with `M-x httpd-start`.
- Start impatient mode in the buffers you're interested to live preview: `M-x impatient-mode`.
- Open your browser to localhost:8080/imp. You'll see the list of buffers with the mode enabled. Click on one: you see live rendering of the buffer.

To enable markdown conversion, we follow wikemacs:

- Define this elisp function somewhere, like in your init file:

  ```
   <!-- language: lang-lisp -->

    (defun markdown-html (buffer)
      (princ (with-current-buffer buffer
        (format "<!DOCTYPE html><html><title>Impatient Markdown</title><xmp theme=\"united\" style=\"display:none;\"> %s  </xmp><script src=\"http://ndossougbe.github.io/strapdown/dist/strapdown.js\"></script></html>" (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
      (current-buffer)))
  ```
- Tell impatient mode to use it: `M-x imp-set-user-filter RET markdown-html RET`.
- Go back to your browser, it works!

#### livedown-mode (with npm)

https://github.com/shime/emacs-livedown requires the `livedown` npm package. Also, this emacs package is not in MELPA, you have to clone it locally. Otherwise, it is a good and lightweight solution.

#### Vmd-mode (npm, Electron)

Another solution is [vmd-mode](https://github.com/blak3mill3r/vmd-mode), which works with the `vmd` node package. This is not the most heavy-weight solution: vmd is based on Electron (!).

#### Grip-mode (Python, Github's rate limit)

Another one is [grip-mode](https://github.com/seagle0128/grip-mode), that relies on a Python package:

```
pip install --user grip

M-x package-install grip-mode
```

Then run `M-x grip-mode` in the markdown buffer. It opens a new tab in your browser.

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, it is limited by Github's rate limit. Indeed, to render content as precisely as Github, it calls its API. It doesn't render content locally. As such we are limited to 60 calls an hour, which is very few. See this issue: https://github.com/joeyespo/grip/issues/35

Comment: By the same author, you might want to check skewer-mode https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode, which provides live interaction with JavaScript, CSS, and HTML in a web browser !

Comment: `impatient-mode` worked beautifully for me! Thanks @Ehvince.

Comment: flymd doesn't work on Firefox since 68, see https://github.com/mola-T/flymd/issues/27

Comment: I modified the code slightly to export my org-mode code as markdown and then display it: `defun markdown-html (buffer) (with-current-buffer buffer (org-md-export-as-markdown)) (princ (with-current-buffer "*Org MD Export*" ...`. Works great as long as `org-export-show-temporary-export-buffer` is `nil`

Comment: The link to the script seems to be broken now for good, I replaced with  `http://ndossougbe.github.io/strapdown/dist/strapdown.js` and got things working again.

Comment: When I type into the EMACS markdown buffer, impatient-mode scrolls my internet browser back to the top of the document. I tested the 26-06-2016 version of Strapdown.js without EMACS and the problem does not happen there, but I have to manually refresh the page in my web browser after making changes. How can I get EMACS impatient-mode to stop auto-scrolling my internet browser when I type in a buffer?

Comment: @ShawnEary Honestly, all solutions in Emacs to live preview Markdown suck. Use vscode. From a long time Emacs user.

Comment: @nephewtom - VSCode works pretty good, but I have problems navigating back to where I started when I test links: https://superuser.com/questions/1671277/go-back-in-visual-studio-code-when-testing-links-in-markdown-preview

Comment: @ShawnEary It seems grip-mode works well out of the box now. i will try it for several weeks to check how it goes.

Comment: @nephewtom - I think grip-mode worked okay for me also, but I'm not necessarily allowed to use it at my day job because it ships the code off to GitHub for processing. GitHub is reputable, but I guess there is some **minimal** risk of your company code getting stolen if you use grip-mode.

Answer (score 17):

I like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11628141/1165509) simpler approach that doesn't require another package nor a browser:

- Execute `M-x markdown-other-window` on current buffer and display the result in other window.
- Change to `M-x html-mode` and hide HTML tags `M-x sgml-tags-invisible`.

Then to update the html buffer run again `markdown-other-window` <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> on the markdown buffer.

Comment: C-c C-c p  can do the same thing now

Comment: But `pandoc` is needed. I just added that as a note on the other question.

Comment: If you still get an error finding the markdown command after installing, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19740648/1949430

Comment: When I try to update the html buffer by running `markdown-other-window` I keep getting the message `Text is read-only`. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Answer (score 10):

You can now do this in Spacemacs with `markdown-live-preview-mode` or `SPC m c p`.

Comment: You can also do this in regular Emacs (At least in `GNU Emacs 26.1`)... Make sure to `brew install markdown` though on Mac

Comment: I found `markdown-live-preview-mode` is equivalent to `SPC m c P` instead of `SPC m c p`. Still thanks for sharing the tip.

Comment: In spacemacs, after pressing `SPC m c p` I get the error at the bottom `Markdown command markdown is not found`.  Any idea why?

Comment: that is a shell program to convert markdown to html. the package depends on that tool. Just install it using apt, pacman, dnf, or whatever your package manager is

Comment: You have to install makdrown package from your system package manager.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. I don't use spacemacs, but I just did ```M-x markdown-live-preview-mode``` et voila !

Answer (score 7):

I would like recommend [grip-mode](https://github.com/seagle0128/grip-mode): Instant Github-flavored Markdown/Org preview.

Comment: thank you in December 2019, this is the best answer.

Comment: Very nice, except for the Github API request limit.

Answer (score 6):

Before following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288851), you would need to have a markdown parser installed on your system **and** a major mode to associate it to, in emacs.

Add emacs package repository to init.el

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

Restart emacs and refresh packages:

`M-x package-refresh-contents`

Install emacs major mode markdown-mode by evaluating:

`M-x package-install RET markdown-mode RET`

Install markdown processor:

```
brew install pandoc
OR
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

Map the markdown parser to the major-mode in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`like:

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(markdown-command "/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer along with the referenced one and it works! I was getting the `Markdown command markdown error` in the mini buffer and could not figure out why

Comment: After installing with homebrew, `which pandoc` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/pandoc` obviously

Answer (score 4):

@Ehvince's answer inspired me to a little bit change the markdown-html function to provide exactly the same view as in Github.com.

```
(defun markdown-html (buffer)
  (princ (with-current-buffer buffer
           (format "<!DOCTYPE html><html><script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/he/1.1.1/he.js\"></script><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github-e6bb18b320358b77abe040d2eb46b547.css\"><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-95aff0b550d3fe338b645a4deebdcb1b.css\"><title>Impatient Markdown</title><div id=\"markdown-content\" style=\"display:none\">%s</div><div class=\"markdown-body\" style=\"max-width:968px;margin:0 auto;\"></div><script>fetch('https://api.github.com/markdown', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({ \"text\": document.getElementById('markdown-content').innerHTML, \"mode\": \"gfm\", \"context\": \"knit-pk/homepage-nuxtjs\"}) }).then(response => response.text()).then(response => {document.querySelector('.markdown-body').innerHTML = he.decode(response)}).then(() => { fetch(\"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/FieryCod/b6938b29531b6ec72de25c76fa978b2c/raw/\").then(response => response.text()).then(eval)});</script></html>"
                   (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
         (current-buffer)))
```

Function which enables the impatient mode and automatically sets the `imp-user-filter` to `markdown-html`.

```
(defun markdown-preview-like-god ()
  (interactive)
  (impatient-mode 1)
  (setq imp-user-filter #'markdown-html)
  (cl-incf imp-last-state)
  (imp--notify-clients))
```

How to use:

1. `M-x httpd-start`
2. On .md buffer `M-x markdown-preview-like-god`
3. Go to `localhost:8080/imp`

Answer (score 3):

You can use my emacs application framework: https://github.com/manateelazycat/emacs-application-framework

It's embed browser in your emacs, then you can write markdown at left side and preview update at right side.

Screenshot at: https://github.com/manateelazycat/emacs-application-framework/blob/master/screenshot/markdown_previewer.gif

How to install eaf please look https://github.com/manateelazycat/emacs-application-framework/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Samuel please don't delete my post, it has include best solution, not just a link